RL error: ROSLAUNCH is not working with ROS Noetic
O.S - Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
ROS version - noetic
I got error while running roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_world.launch. The error is as follows
RLException: [turtlebot_world.launch] is neither a launch file in package [turtlebot_gazebo] nor is [turtlebot_gazebo] a launch file name
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file

I opened a terminal and start running roscore, which run error free. I opened another terminal. 1st source the global ROS there using command source /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash. Then I navigate to catkin_ws. I sourced ROS there using the command source devel/setup.bash. After that I ran the roslaunch command. I build the workspace previously using catkin_make.
How can I solve the problem?
Thank you.
